# Can I port my existing python apps on ASE?

Tags: python, android, ase, android-scripting

I learned that the Android Scripting Environment (ASE) supports python code. Can I take my existing python programs and run them on android?

Apart from the GUI, what else will I need to adapt? How can I find the list of supported python libraries for ASE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of yet, there is no support for a gui on ASE apart from some simple input and display dialogs. Look at /sdcard/ase/extras/python to find libraries already available. You can add new libraries by copying them there.

Comment: It's such a shame that the use of Python on Android is so limited, I would really like for more functionality to be provided to Python applications.